# Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, undefined, referenceerror

keep getting Uncaught Reference Error: 'message' is not defined ,
here is the code:

```
   class ChatApp {
  constructor(){
    //console.log('ChatApp constructor');
    socket.init('ws://localhost:8000');
    socket.registerOpenHandler(() => {
      let message = new ChatMessage({ message: 'Hello' });
      socket.sendMessage(message.serialize());
    });
    socket.registerMessageHandler((data) => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
}

class ChatMessage {
  constructor({
    message: m,
    user: u='Nader',
    timestamp: t=(new Date()).getTime()
  }) {
    this.message = message;
    this.user = user;
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
    console.log(message);
  }
  serialize(){
    return {
      message: this.message,
      user: this.user,
      timestamp: this.timestamp

    };
  }
}
```

although I defined message on line 5 using let message ....
please help, thanks

Comment: You do realize you're renaming during destructuring? It's `m` not `message`.

Comment: Same for `user` and `timestamp`.

Comment: @Andrew Li you're correct

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong variable names, use what you pass inside the constructor,

```
 this.message = m;
 this.user = u;
 this.timestamp = t;
 console.log(message);
```

Comment: Thanks Sajeetharan,

the error is now occurring on line 19:

 message: m, 

(Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined)

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding it correctly, your constructor is setting your class values equal to the types and not the passed values.

Comment: see @Sajeetharan for what I am referring to.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your ChatMessage constructor. The keys are being renamed to a single character, but they are not being used in the body of the constructor.

Should be:

```
constructor({
    message: m, 
    user: u='Nader',
    timestamp: t=(new Date()).getTime()
  }) {
    this.message = m; 
    this.user = u;
    this.timestamp = t;
  }
```

Comment: you were absolutely correct, I did that and it worked